# Derive groups of records that match over multiple columns, but where some column values might be NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like an efficient means of deriving groups of matching records across multiple fields. Let's say I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cust
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    class VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    cust_type VARCHAR(1) NULL,
    terms VARCHAR(1) NULL
);

INSERT INTO cust
VALUES
    (1,'A',NULL,'C'),
    (2,NULL,'B','C'),
    (3,'A','B',NULL),
    (4,NULL,NULL,'C'),
    (5,'D','E',NULL),
    (6,'D',NULL,NULL);
```

What I am looking to get is the set of IDs for which matching values unify a set of records over the three fields (class, cust_type and terms), so that I can apply a unique ID to the group.

In the example, records 1-4 constitute one match group over the three fields, while records 5-6 form a separate match.

<del>The following does the job:</del>

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    a.id,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY max(b.class),max(b.cust_type),max(b.terms)) AS match_group
FROM cust AS a
INNER JOIN
    cust AS b
ON
    a.class = b.class
    OR a.cust_type = b.cust_type
    OR a.terms = b.terms
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id

id match_group
-- -----------
 1 1
 2 1
 3 1
 4 1
 5 2
 6 2
```

<del>**But, is there a better way?** Running this query on a table of over a million rows is painful...</del>

**As Graham pointed out in the comments, the above query doesn't satisfy the requirements if another record is added that would group all the records together.**

The following values should be grouped together in one group:

```
INSERT INTO cust
VALUES
    (1,'A',NULL,'C'),
    (2,NULL,'B','C'),
    (3,'A','B',NULL),
    (4,NULL,NULL,'C'),
    (5,'D','E',NULL),
    (6,'D',NULL,NULL),
    (7,'D','B','C');
```

Would yield:

```
id match_group
-- -----------
 1 1
 2 1
 3 1
 4 1
 5 1
 6 1
```

...because the *class* value of *D* groups records 5, 6 and 7. The *terms* value of *C* matches records 1, 2 and 4 to that group, and *cust_type* value *B* ( or *class* value *A*) pulls in record 3.

Hopefully that all makes sense.

Comment: Can you explain in words how records are 'matched'?

Comment: If your data had D/B/C, then I don't think your matching would work.  You need to think through the logic a bit more clearly.

Comment: @TT. In this case, I just mean the values are the same against the specific column. So the class value for id=1 is the same as class value for id=3, so I know they represent the same "cust" entity.

Comment: @Lee Ok so 1 & 3 match, but you state that 1, 2, 3 & 4 all match into one group over the three fields. It would be good to have a formal explanation to show that these records all belong to the same group.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Gah - yes, you're correct. But, if there was another record with those values, I would want the query to return one grouping ID, the class and terms values unifying all the records... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with a (recursive) Select.
I did something similar (trying to identify unique households) using a temporary table & repeated updates using following logic:

For each `class|cust_type|terms` get the minimum `id` and update that temp table:

```
update temp
from
 (
  SELECT
    class, -- similar for cust_type & terms
    min(id) as min_id
  from temp
  group by class
 ) x
set id = min_id
where temp.class = x.class
  and temp.id <> x.min_id
;
```

Repeat all three updates until *none* of them updates a row.